# php preg_replace url

Tags: php, regex

> By Chris Sheridan MADRID, Spain --
>   Rudy Fernandez is not returning calls
>   from Portland Trail Blazers coach Nate
>   McMillan and was fined $25000 by the
>   NBA on ... var make_url =
>   'http://goog.com/Escape_Space_Link';

My question is how do I use regex and php's preg_replace to remove the entire var make_url = 'http://goog.com/Escape_Space_Link'

Please note that http://goog.com/Escape_Space_Link may change, but it's always a url

Thank you!

Comment: Will the link always be the same? and will it always be at the end of the string?

Comment: The link will keep changing, and it's not always at the end of the string. Thanks!

Comment: How do you get that string in the first place? It looks like someone run strip_tags() on some HTML. In such case, it'd be better to run an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the same string you want to remove, use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead.

```
$string = str_replace("var make_url = 'http://goog.com/Escape_Space_Link'", "", $inputString);
```

If it's always "var make_url = 'http://someurl';", you can use this preg_replace to remove the url:

```
$string = preg_replace("/var make_url = 'http:\/\/.+';/", "", $inputString);
```

Comment: From the OP - `Please note that http://goog.com/Escape_Space_Link may change, but it's always a url`